# Import data from local machine to custom object

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

I have a requirement to import data from local machine(user placed .csv files in a common location) to the custom object with out user interference on hourly basis.could you please give suggestions to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of requirement, we use Data Loader CLI. You need to write windows batch script to export data into Salesforce.

There is a step by step guide to do this.

[Data Loader Command Line Introduction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm)

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thank you for your advise. In my requirement user don't want to do any thing except create a csv file and place it in folder.I need to develop a functionality such that i need to read that file and import the data to the custom object.

Comment: @Suresh then DATA loader CLI will be perfect for you.

Comment: @Suresh Salesforce cannot directly read any data in your network by any code you write in Salesforce. What you would do is use the Data Loader CLI and set up a cron job or Windows Task to perform the hourly upload.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier way, but you could export your org's API and write some back office code to connect to Salesforce, parse the CSV files, create your custom object records, and then send them off to Salesforce.
A simple batch or cron job will have it running hourly.
I know that this works, since we're doing something similar but a lot more complex. But this might be a case of using a nuclear bomb to hammer a nail...
If you want to do that, here's the place to start: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm